# Array with dynamic field names

Tags: jquery, arrays

I am passing this function different field names on each call.  I would like it to post the interpolated string value of the variable `field` as the name of the posted var.  Eg one post might have

```
data: { 'shoppingCartContents' : cartrow, 'number' : number, 'foo' : value }
```

but every post just has

```
data: { 'shoppingCartContents' : cartrow, 'number' : number, 'field' : value }
```

even though `field` is not in quotes.

```
function update_personalization(cartrow, number, field, value) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'updatePersonalization.php',
    data: { 'shoppingCartContents' : cartrow, 'number' : number, field : value }
  });
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to build the object differently:

```
   data: (function() {
     var rv = {shoppingCartContents: cartrow, number: number};
     rv[field] = value;
     return rv;
   })()
```

What that does is build up the object you want to pass as "data" in a little anonymous function. The function initializes a simple object with the static field names, then adds the dynamically-named field in a separate statement.

That's not really an "array", for what it's worth.

Comment: Thanks Pointy.  Much obliged!